# After initiating a pybuilder project I receive an error that the executable is not functioning and that virtualenv is not compatible

Tags: python, virtualenv, pybuilder

I'm following the following helloworld tutuorial for pybuilder: https://pybuilder.io/documentation/tutorial
I'm using a mac. I've installed python with brew.
I'm able to run the following commands:

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install pybuilder
$ pyb --start-project
```

I create the helloworld file and run:

```
$ pyb
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The executable /Users/myusername/projects/learning/pybuilderexample/helloworld/.pybuilder/plugins/cpython-3.9.1.final.0/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9' (should be '/Users/myusername/projects/learning/pybuilder-example/helloworld/.pybuilder/plugins/cpython-3.9.1.final.0')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Can anyone help me get past this error? I think it has something to do with the way I installed python (brew). However, I'm unsure what to do next.

Comment: Additional Info: I've tried re-installing Python 3.9. I've also tried clearing out the directory and starting the tutorial over. I still get this same error every time.

Comment: For anyone interested I ended up giving up on this and using pyenv.